# Перейти к следующему слову, при встрече в данном набора символов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть функция, обрезающая слишком длинные слова (аналог wordwrap)

```
function mBwordwrap($text, $width, $break = "\n")
{
   return preg_replace('#([^\s]{'. $width .'})#u', '$1'. $break , $text);
}
```

так вот, мне необходимо, чтобы эта функция не затрагивала ссылки (ибо они-то уж бывают действительно длинными в атрибутах изображений, например). Как сделать, чтобы при нахождении в слове http:// ,например, это слово не было затронуто?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выражений для поиска ссылок десятки, можете даже на этом форуме найти что-нибудь подходящее. Использую самую простую вариацию.

```
$HREF="https?:\/\/[^ ]+";
```

Ваше выражение:

```
$LONG="[^\\s]{". $width ."}";
```

Код:

```
preg_replace_callback("/(?:$HREF)|(?P<word>$LONG)/u", "clb", $text);
function clb ($arr) {
    if ($arr["word"]) return $arr["word"].$break;
    return $arr[0];
};
```

Comment: ожидал ваш ответ на вопрос о регулярных выражениях :)

+1.

Comment: хм...круто, спасибо большое! :)

Comment: Не за что. Поправил ответ для большей универсальности.